# Find xpath from UI automator frames

Tags: android, xpath, appium, android-uiautomator

I am automating one of the native app in android by using appium. I facing one issue during finding out the xpath from uiautomator. it is working fine in all cases but i stuck in one case please find attached image. In this i am not able to get the resource id , class name of any field, even i am not able to select that particular filed like first name , last name, whole frame layout is selecting at once. Please help if any one have idea.

[image]

I want to find class name , resource id of all fields.

Comment: yes this is a webview

Comment: This is the issue i have faced too. Nothing you can do. Ask developers if they can add unique id for each field.

Answer (score 0):

It's an `UIAutomator` limitiation.. `UIAutomator` only detects the objects listed in `XML layouts`, please ask your developers to add the `objects` in `XML map` as well